# How to force English language in MVC 5 ASP.NET field validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, data-annotations

The title says it all... But for sure I'll give an example.

I used a DataAnnotation on my property:

```
[StringLength(120), MinLength(3)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

And on invalid input the generated error message is in my mother language, not in English:

```
Pole Title musi być ciągiem lub typem tablicy o minimalnej długości 3.
```

How to force English language in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the globalization culture and uiculture attributes in your web.config set to "auto", it'll use the browser client's language. Presumably, that's set to your mother language. If you want to force it to use English, set

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" />
```

in your web.config. (It's in the system.web element.)

Comment: It wont _use the browser client's language_. It will use the servers default language :)

Comment: Nope. It uses the preferred client language. "You can also set the value to auto which will perform automatic detection of the browser's preferred language and set it. The automatic language detection can be qualified with a default value such as auto:en-us." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.culture.aspx